# How to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, geometric-series

> How to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n2^n}$?

I think it convergences but do not know how to compute it.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} = -\log(1-x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}$ for $0<x<1$ and compute $F(x) = \int f(x) dx$. The consider $F(1/2)$.

Comment: Do you mean $\int f(x)dx$?

Comment: @KentaS yes fixed thx